# XSLT as substitution application: instantiating "XML macros"

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to use XSLT for creating multiple instances of an XML pattern from one XML file based on a key value map specified in a different XML file, for reference see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_%28logic%29. 
The XSL should be applied to the key value map (the substitution), which contains a reference to the pattern. 
I am guessing that this can be accomplished with a general (and possibly elegant) solution, but I don't know how to proceed.

An example is the following:

*Pattern: (pattern.xml)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pattern>
  <key1>a</key1>
  <element2>key2</element2>
  <element3 attribute="key2">key1</element3>
</pattern>
```

*Key value map: (substitution.xml)* (*Update:* renaming from input.xml)

**Update:** the substitution should contain a reference to the pattern, and work in common browsers, which I understand requires the use of XSLT 1.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="apply-substitution.xsl"?>
<root pattern="http://example.com/link-to-pattern.xml">
  <copy>
    <key1>VALUE1</key1>
    <key2>VALUE2</key2>
    <key3>VALUE3</key3>
  </copy>
    <copy>
    <key1>VALUE3</key1>
    <key2>VALUE4</key2>
    <key3>VALUE5</key3>
  </copy>
</root>
```

The result of "applying" the map to the pattern should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<some_root>
<!-- instance 1 -->
<pattern>
  <VALUE1>a</VALUE1>
  <element2>VALUE2</element2>
  <element3 attribute="VALUE2">VALUE1</element3>
</pattern>

<!-- instance 2 -->
<pattern>
  <VALUE3>a</VALUE3>
  <element2>VALUE4</element2>
  <element3 attribute="VALUE4">VALUE3</element3>
</pattern>
</some_root>
```

... creating instances of the pattern where all element names, attribute names and values (matching the whole value, e.g., not substrings) are placed as specified by the key value map.

My use case is that the pattern is a very complex XML structure (not designed by me) that I want to create (a potentially very large set of) instances of -- keeping the structure of the pattern and most of the content as-is, but changing some nodes, which may appear in any position of the pattern XML, i.e., element name, attribute name, and values (matching the complete value). The sum of the pattern instances form a complete and sound dataset in the pattern XML language. Consider the pattern as a kind of a macro that is called or instantiated by each `<copy>` in input.xml.

My solution so far only replicates the pattern without replacing values:

```
[removed since irrelevant due to updates. New version below]
```

**Update:**
The following is a start (however, contains bugs as noted by @Eiríkr's answer, and uses hardcoded reference to pattern.xml). It substitute elements, attribute names and values, and text nodes --- and apply recursively.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="pattern" select="document('pattern.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="*/copy">
    <xsl:call-template name="substitute-element">
      <xsl:with-param name="element" select="$pattern"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="map" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>    
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="substitute-element">
    <xsl:param name="element"/>
    <xsl:param name="map"/>

    <!-- substitute element name -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$element/*">

      <xsl:variable name="elementName">
    <xsl:call-template name="substitute-value">
      <xsl:with-param name="value" select="name(.)"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="map" select="$map"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:element name="{$elementName}">

    <!-- replace attributes -->
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
      <xsl:variable name="attrName">
        <xsl:call-template name="substitute-value">
          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="name(.)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="map" select="$map"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>


      <xsl:attribute name="{$attrName}">
        <!-- replace attribute value -->
        <xsl:call-template name="substitute-value">
          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="."/>
          <xsl:with-param name="map" select="$map"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each>


    <!-- replace element text node -->
    <xsl:call-template name="substitute-value">
      <xsl:with-param name="value" select="text()"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="map" select="$map"/>
    </xsl:call-template>


    <!-- recurse -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$element/*">
      <xsl:call-template name="substitute-element">
        <xsl:with-param name="element" select="."/>
        <xsl:with-param name="map" select="$map"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>

      </xsl:element>

    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="substitute-value">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:param name="map"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- search for matching key -->
      <xsl:when test="$map/*[name(.)=$value]">
    <xsl:value-of select="$map/*[name(.)=$value]/text()"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- default to incoming value if matching key not found -->
      <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perhaps one could write an XSLT transform for this, but I think it would be pretty messy -- no elegance there.  It looks like what you really want is a simple global search&replace, since evidently you want to perform replacements everywhere -- element names, attribute values (and names?), and text.  Ordinarily I would urge using XML tools to work with XML, as indeed you propose to do.  Since you seem not to be relying on the document's XML structure, however, maybe a simple `sed`, `awk`, or `perl` script would be a better choice.

Comment: A couple confusing points: 1) Your result has upper-case `VALUE` where your map has lower-case `value`.  Is this intentional?  2) Your map has a `key3` element in each repeated structure, but this isn't actually used anywhere.  Is this also intentional?  -- Past there, I would agree with John: this looks more like a scripted search-and-replace, for which other (non-XSL) languages might be better suited.

Comment: 1) Sorry about the casing error, I edited after writing the question to make it easier to read and forgot input.xml. 2) Yes, this is intentional; the map may contain keys that do not occur in the pattern.

Comment: I can agree to the point of using a different tool for the job. However, in this case I need to use XSLT. Any ideas of how I can apply an identity transform plus renamings to only the pattern file?

Comment: Do you want to substitute values for keys only when they match the whole node name or value (every case in your example fits this criterion), or do you also have to match keys appearing as substrings?

Comment: Let me restate what I think you're asking, to check that I'm barking up the right tree :).  You have one input XML file, and you need to process this one input file N times with N output files.  Each iteration of N will have its own set of replacements, as defined in the map file.  -- Is this correct?  Is there one set of keys for each N (i.e. number of key sets == N), or are some iterations using the same set of keys (such as, iterations 1-14 use set 1, iterations 15-22 use set 2, etc. etc.)?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, only complete names and values should be matched, not substrings.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi, not exactly, assuming I understand you correctly. I have added a paragraph "My use case ..." to explain. It that understandable?

Comment: Due to new development by @EiríkrÚtlendi, replacing the example solution in question with my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

### The XSL code in your answer post

You asked, *"is it possible to avoid passing $map around everywhere?"*

If you're going to cross-apply different XML structures this way, then you're probably going to need to pass in parameters.

That aside, I do note the following:

- In the XSL code in your answer, you have two files: `input.xml` and `pattern.xml`.  The names are misleading -- you need to apply the patterns in `input.xml` to the XML structures in `pattern.xml`.  For a smoother flow and more-natural XSL-y way of processing, we'd want to reference `input.xml`, and actually input `pattern.xml` instead.  Doing this also makes your XSL stylesheet more flexible -- you can pass it any file instead of `pattern.xml`, without needing to edit the XSL itself to change the hard-coded path.
- It might make even more sense to simply include all the key-value replacements you define in the external `input.xml` file right in the XSL itself.
- As a further consideration, XSL is inherently recursive if you use `match`ing templates with `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, instead of using `name`d templates.
- The output from your code doesn't conform to your stated specifications when the `<pattern>` XML structure is extended.  For instance, extending the XML as follows:

  ```
  <pattern>
      <key1>a</key1>
      <element2>key2</element2>
      <element3 attribute="key2">key1</element3>
      <element4>
          <key3>something <key1>and something else with <another key1="key1">key2</another> content.</key1></key3>
      </element4>
  </pattern>
  ```

  ...and applying your code produces too much output:

  ```
  <root>
     <pattern>
        <VALUE1>a<VALUE3>something <VALUE1>and something else with <another VALUE1="VALUE1">VALUE2</another>
              </VALUE1>
           </VALUE3>
        </VALUE1>
        <element2>VALUE2<VALUE3>something <VALUE1>and something else with <another VALUE1="VALUE1">VALUE2</another>
              </VALUE1>
           </VALUE3>
        </element2>
        <element3 attribute="VALUE2">VALUE1<VALUE3>something <VALUE1>and something else with <another VALUE1="VALUE1">VALUE2</another>
              </VALUE1>
           </VALUE3>
        </element3>
        <element4>
          <VALUE3>something <VALUE1>and something else with <another VALUE1="VALUE1">VALUE2</another>
              </VALUE1>
           </VALUE3>
        </element4>
     </pattern>
     <pattern>
        <VALUE3>a<VALUE5>something <VALUE3>and something else with <another VALUE3="VALUE3">VALUE4</another>
              </VALUE3>
           </VALUE5>
        </VALUE3>
        <element2>VALUE4<VALUE5>something <VALUE3>and something else with <another VALUE3="VALUE3">VALUE4</another>
              </VALUE3>
           </VALUE5>
        </element2>
        <element3 attribute="VALUE4">VALUE3<VALUE5>something <VALUE3>and something else with <another VALUE3="VALUE3">VALUE4</another>
              </VALUE3>
           </VALUE5>
        </element3>
        <element4>
          <VALUE5>something <VALUE3>and something else with <another VALUE3="VALUE3">VALUE4</another>
              </VALUE3>
           </VALUE5>
        </element4>
     </pattern>
  </root>
  ```

  If I've understood your requirements correctly, what you'd want instead would be:

  ```
  <root>
     <pattern>
        <VALUE1>a</VALUE1>
        <element2>VALUE2</element2>
        <element3 attribute="VALUE2">VALUE1</element3>
        <element4>
          <VALUE3>something <VALUE1>and something else with <another VALUE1="VALUE1">VALUE2</another> content.</VALUE1>
           </VALUE3>
        </element4>
     </pattern>
     <pattern>
        <VALUE3>a</VALUE3>
        <element2>VALUE4</element2>
        <element3 attribute="VALUE4">VALUE3</element3>
        <element4>
          <VALUE5>something <VALUE3>and something else with <another VALUE3="VALUE3">VALUE4</another> content.</VALUE3>
           </VALUE5>
        </element4>
     </pattern>
  </root>
  ```

### An alternative approach

After chewing on this for a while to make sure I understood what you're trying to do, I realized that part of my initial difficulty in understanding your code is that you start out by working on the `input.xml` file and dealing with that context, and then you change to working on the `pattern.xml` file and dealing with that context.

When you call a template and you want that template to process something (and not just return a static value or XML structure), you have to explicitly pass in that something, and this can make context confusing.  Here is another way of tackling your same problem, using `<xsl:apply-templates>` instead of `<xsl:call-template name="...">`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- We need to create output based on processing the 
        `pattern.xml` file, so we use that as our input. -->

    <!-- Despite its name, the `input.xml` file actually contains
        the pattern we wish to apply to the incoming XML file. 
        We'll store this pattern in a variable here. -->
    <xsl:variable name="replacements" select="document('input.xml')">
        <!-- Rather than relying on external files, we could leave out the
            `select` attribute and just put all the replacement information 
            right here in the XSL file. --><!--
        <root>
            <copy>
                <key1>VALUE1</key1>
                <key2>VALUE2</key2>
                <key3>VALUE3</key3>
            </copy>
            <copy>
                <key1>VALUE3</key1>
                <key2>VALUE4</key2>
                <key3>VALUE5</key3>
            </copy>
        </root>-->
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- We assume that we don't know the names of any of the elements
        or attributes in the file we're processing. 
        If you _do_ know any of those names, specify them: literal
        XPaths tend to be faster. -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- We put the top-level XML structure into a variable so 
            we can refer to it from within the for-each. If we 
            don't do this, we can't get at it: within the for-each,
            both the `.` operator and the `current()` function
            refer to the context item for the `for-each` call,
            and _not_ to the context item for the `template match`
            statement.  The `child::` axis in the `select` statement
            is optional; we could just use `select="*"` instead.
            I added the `child::` to make it clear for humans. -->
        <xsl:variable name="top" select="child::*"/>
        <!-- At the root level, we want to create a copy of the 
            topmost element from the $replacements variable. -->
        <xsl:element name="{name($replacements/*[1])}">
            <!-- We want to apply the key-value pairs to the topmost
                XML structure from the input file, once for each 
                instance of <copy> in the $replacements variable. -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$replacements/*/copy">
                <!-- Now we apply our templates to the input
                    file structure, which we stored in $top. -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$top">
                    <!-- We do need to have some way of knowing which
                        `copy` we want to reference, so we pass this
                        along as a parameter. -->
                    <xsl:with-param name="this" select="."/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- This matches all elements. -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:param name="this"/>
        <!-- We compare the current element name against all the 
            element names in $this, and use that value if found,
            or the current element name if not found. -->
        <xsl:element name="{if (name(.) = $this//*/name())
            then ($this//*[name() = name(current())])
            else (name(.))}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()">
                <xsl:with-param name="this" select="$this"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- This matches all atributes.  We evaluate both attribute
        names and attribute values, allowing us to replace either
        or both, if they match the key-value pairs in $this.-->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:param name="this"/>
        <xsl:variable name="attname" select="if (name(.) = $this//*/name())
            then ($this//*[name() = name(current())])
            else (name(.))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="attval" select="if (. = $this//*/name())
            then ($this//*[name() = current()])
            else (.)"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="{$attname}" select="$attval"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- This matches all text. -->
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:param name="this"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="if (. = $this//*/name())
            then ($this//*[name() = current()])
            else (.)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

From your post, it wasn't entirely clear if you are restricted to XSL 1.0.  I used XSL 2.0 above, and the `if () then () else ()` logic in XPath expressions only works in XSL 2.0+.  The use of `*/name()` on the end of an XPath expression is also unsupported in XSL 1.0.  Both of these issues can be coded around as needed.

This XSL produces the (I believe expected?) shorter XML output from the extended input XML with the `<element4>` addition.

#### Update - XSL 1.0 version

The following is largely equivalent to the previous XSL above, but reworked to be compatible with XSL 1.0.  The main differences:

- Changed the filename referenced in the `$replacements` variable to `substitution.xml`.
- Created a named template to replace the `if () then () else ()` logic inline in the XSL 2.0+ XPath expressions.
- Created variables within templates to call that template and store the value.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Filename changed to match the new requirements. -->
    <xsl:variable name="replacements" select="document('substitution.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="top" select="*"/>
        <xsl:element name="{name($replacements/*[1])}">
            <xsl:for-each select="$replacements/*/copy">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$top">
                    <xsl:with-param name="this" select="."/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- This matches all elements. -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:param name="this"/>
        <xsl:variable name="elem_name">
            <!-- XSL 1.0 does not support `if / then / else` logic in
                XPath statements, so we use this variable instead to
                call a named template containing the logic, and then
                to store the resulting value. -->
            <xsl:call-template name="get_sub_value">
                <xsl:with-param name="this" select="$this"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="val" select="name()"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="{$elem_name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()">
                <xsl:with-param name="this" select="$this"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- This matches all atributes. -->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:param name="this"/>
        <xsl:variable name="attname">
            <xsl:call-template name="get_sub_value">
                <xsl:with-param name="this" select="$this"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="val" select="name()"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:attribute name="{$attname}">
            <!-- For attribute alues, we just call `get_sub_value` directly. -->
            <xsl:call-template name="get_sub_value">
                <xsl:with-param name="this" select="$this"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="val" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- This matches all text. -->
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:param name="this"/>
        <!-- For straight text, we just call `get_sub_value` directly. -->
        <xsl:call-template name="get_sub_value">
            <xsl:with-param name="this" select="$this"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="val" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Named template to handle the logic of looking for key-value pairs
        in the relevant `<copy>` element from the `substitution.xml` file. -->
    <xsl:template name="get_sub_value">
        <xsl:param name="this"/>
        <xsl:param name="val"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$this//*[name() = $val]">
                <xsl:value-of select="$this//*[name() = $val]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$val"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am a bit puzzled about what your use case would be for doing this in a browser, but you know what you need.  :)

Tested in Oxygen XML v17.1, using the Xalan, Saxon 6.5, and Saxon 9.6.0.7 processors.  The only differences were the indentation.

Comment: Thanks! This is very valuable. I have comments and answers, but uncertain of how to best do this in SO. How about I move my own accepted answer into the initial question and extend the initial question and adding comments to answer your answer?

Comment: @mgs, I'm no expert in SO best practices, but that sounds fine by me.  :)

Comment: Comments to your notes (now numbered): (1.) I have renamed input.xml to substitution.xml (as "input" is a bad name anyway). But I disagree with your new "application direction". Although your solution might be more XSL-y, only the substitution should know about the pattern, not the other way around. (2.) See (1.) and also, there may be many different substitutions, the XSL should be generic to both substitution and pattern. I have updated the question to reflex this. (3). Great! I did know know how to do this. (4) Thanks! (Other:) I think I need XSL 1.0 for max. browser support.

Comment: @mgs, I'm not sure I fully understand your comment that _"only the substitution should know about the pattern"_.  In the code above, so long as `$replacements` loads a file from a path you control, then you can feed in any input file (I think that's your _"pattern"_?) and matching `key`s will be replaced with the corresponding `VALUE`s.  Does that do what you need?

Comment: Eiríkr, what I ment was that substitution.xml contains the path to pattern.xml (and not the other way around) such that the document() call should take pattern.xml as input, and not substitution.xml.